# How can I count subfolders in a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, subdirectory, working-directory

I need the count of the longest path in my folder and put it in a variable. Because when I remove recursively subfolders I have to do it multiple times to check if there is other empty folders.

```
FOR /l %%y IN (0, 1, 3) DO (
FOR /r "%MyPath%" /d %%F IN (.) DO DIR /b "%%F" | findstr "^" > NUL || RD "%%F"
)
```

I don't know if there is a parameter that I can use to remove all of my empty subfolders but all I found is this way and I need to replace the 3 with the count of subfolders in my biggest path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir /s /b /ad "%sourcedir%"^|sort /r') do dir /b "%%s"|findstr "^" > NUL|| RD "%%s"
```

should delete your empty directories.

The `dir` command lists the directories in the tree rooted at `sourcedir`. This is sorted in reverse order so the subdirectories of any subdirectory are processed before the subdirectory.

I'd target a test directory for - well, testing...